# Disabled jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can we get rid of the dim version of a disabled html control? I mean is it possible that html control or particularly in my case jquery datepicker's css looks like enabled even in the disbabled state?

Please see the enabled and disabled versions of the datepicker. I want to make it disabled with the enabled look. Is it possible?

[image] [image]

Comment: code is just that `$("#date").datepicker({disabled:true});` @Danko

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: yes, just change the css to suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

The visual differences are all done by css. You just need to adapt the css to suit your needs.

Inspect the various rules in browser console/ developer tools to see what rules apply to specific elements and write new rules that over ride them

Comment: Specifically look for the class `ui-state-disabled` and override the styles to suit your use-case.